# How to Click on item in Flatlist to display another component without displaying it in the drawer

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, react-native-flatlist, react-native-navigation

I have 2 screens in the drawer, one of them includes the Flatlist, what I need to do is to have a drawer with these 2 screens only but when the user clicks on an item in the flatList, another component (with a new screen) should appear with the item details.
Here's the app.js

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
function App() {
  const [expenseList, setExpenseList] = useState([]);
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <ExpenseContext.Provider value={{ expenseList, setExpenseList }}>
        <Drawer.Navigator>
          <Drawer.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Home} />
          <Drawer.Screen name="AddItem" component={AddItem} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      </ExpenseContext.Provider>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
export default App;
```

and here's the part of the FlatList in the Home screen

```
 <FlatList
        contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 20 }}
        style={styles.listContainer}
        data={expenseList}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.key}

        renderItem={(data) => (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Detail")}>
            <View style={styles.info}>

              <View>
                <Text>{data.item.name}</Text>
                <Text numberOfLines={1}>
                  {data.item.description}
                </Text>
                <Text>{data.item.date}</Text>
              </View>

              <View>
                <Text>{data.item.amount}</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      />
```

ps: I am using v6,Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use nested stack navigation with drawer.

```
function App() {
  const [expenseList, setExpenseList] = useState([]);
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <ExpenseContext.Provider value={{ expenseList, setExpenseList }}>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={DrawerNavigation}
            options={{ headerShown: false }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen name="Detail" component={Detail} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </ExpenseContext.Provider>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
export default App;
```

In DrawerNavigation.js

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function DrawerNavigation() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Home} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="AddItem" component={AddItem} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}
export default DrawerNavigation;
```